# Converting list to list of dictionaries in Ansible adding constant fields using filters

Tags: filter, ansible

I have a list of URLs which I get from a previous step:

```
- "example.com"
- "stackoverflow.com"
- "duckduckgo.com"
```

To use it, it needs to be in the format of a list of dicts:

```
{
    "address": "example.com",
    "module": "http_2xx",
    "name": "example.com"
},
{
    "address": "stackoverflow.com",
    "module": "http_2xx",
    "name": "stackoverflow.com"
},
{
    "address": "duckduckgo.com",
    "module": "http_2xx",
    "name": "duckduckgo.com"
}
```

So basically, each element should be converted to a dictionary individually, where the `module` is constant, and `address` and `name` are the item.

It does work using a loop like this:

```
- name: Build dict
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    targets: "{{ targets +  [{ 'name': item, 'address': item, 'module': 'http_2xx' }] }}"
  loop: "{{ targets_list }}"
```

But Ansible loops are too slow for the length of the list. So I'm trying to change it to use filters.

In Python I achieved this by using `map` but I had to use a lambda function which Ansible does not support.

```
list(map(lambda x: {"address": x, "module": "http_2xx", "name": x}, targets_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jinja2 has [`{% for` loops](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for); while I wish it had comprehensions, too, we have to make do with what we have

```yaml
- name: Build dict
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    targets: >-
      {%- set results = [] -%}
      {%- for item in target_list -%}
      {%-   set _ = results.append({ 'name': item, 'address': item, 'module': 'http_2xx' }) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ results }}
```